# How come this throws a c2109(Not a pointer or array type)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So in this code, I am trying to deduce what T non-generic type is. Now T is either is arithmetic type, vector type or a vector of vectors(AKA matrix). This piece of code is causing C2109 runtime  error decrying that  data is not a vector/array or pointer, even though I never tested with a vector nor should it be executed in the first place. And even if it was executed, it should be legal to randomly access the elements of data because the else if statement checks if T is a vector or not. So why is it throwing an error when it should never be executed in the first place and should be legal to do even if it was executed?

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
T2 F1(T data)
{

    if (std::is_arithmetic<T>()) {
        std::cout << "Working scalar " << std::endl;
        return data + 1;
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, std::vector<T2> >()) {
        //Creates C2109
        return data[0] + 1;
    }
    else {
        //Its only matrix in our program

        //Also creates a C2109
        return data[0][0] + 1;
    }
}
template<typename T,typename T2>
T2 taskgraph_sequental(T a)
{
    T2 b = F1<T,T2>(a);
    return b;
}
int main()
{

    //Begin testing with all a inbuilt type 
    int a = 3;
    int val_4 = taskgraph_sequental<int,int>(a);
    std::cout << val_4 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please always post code in [mcve] form.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `if constexpr` to make the code not error when the branch isn’t hit.

```
if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic<T>())
...
else if constexpr(std::is_same<T, std::vector<T2>>())
```

Comment: Interesting. This is the first time anyone doing this and I was wondering why does this not generate errors and mine does. Is it because all the constants are already evaluated at compile time? Is there another way to get the same functionality?

Comment: `if` needs to compile all the branches of its code. `if constexpr` knows which branch will be taken at compile time, and can discard the other ones. So the fact that `data[0]` is a problem when `T` is an arithmetic type matters for the `if`, but not the `if constexpr`.

Comment: Is it always a good idea to  state constexpr always in control flow statements? Because this seems like a optimization step that should always be done

Comment: @Recker12: this is more about semantics than optimization. C++ didn’t really have constant evaluation at the beginning so all code is compiled, no matter if it’s a dead branch. Only in C++11 `if constexpr` was added to aid meta programming. I would use it in every place possible, but that turns out to be not a lot of places - most if’s have runtime conditions, not compile time.